# ThreadExceptionEventHandler in .NET Windows Forms Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

in a Windows Forms Control, I make use of the ThreadExceptionEventHandler where I handle exceptions. Unfortunately, if an application uses my Windows Forms Control it appears that the application's exceptions get trapped by the ThreadExceptionEventHandler of my Windows Forms Control.
Is there another event handler that I can use that would limit the scope of the ThreadExceptionEventHandler to only the exceptions that happened in my Windows Forms Control ?

Thank you

Comment: There is no ".NET UserControl". Please indicate WinForms, WebForms, WPF or other.

Comment: sorry about that - I have edited the question. I am talking about a Windows Forms Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a UserControl should not interfere with Application exception handling. Just take care of your local business, hands of the rest.

If your Control starts Threads, they should normally take care of exceptions. Anything left over is not the Controls responsibility.

Comment: Thank you. So .. if the application that uses my Windows Forms Control has its own global exception handler, the exception handler in my Windows Forms Control should not interfere with it, correct ?

Comment: Yes. That also saves you from writing 20 extra pages of documentation. Keep things simple.